# Como converter um objeto JSON para XML em AS3?

Tags: json, xml, actionscript-3, conversão-de-tipo

Existe algum método de conversão de um objeto JSON para um objeto XML usando o [actionscript-3](/questions/tagged/actionscript-3) com Flash CS6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui efetuar a conversão criando este método que funcionou bem:

```js
function jsonToXML(obj:Object):XML {
    var to:XML = new XML(<root></root>);
    ad(to, obj);
    function ad(c:*, b:*):void {
       for(var a:Object in b) {
          if(b[a].toString() == "[object Object]") {
              c.appendChild(<{a}></{a}>);
              ad(c[a], b[a]);
          }
          else {
              c.appendChild(<{a}>{b[a]}</{a}>);
          }
       }
    }
    return to;
}
```

Comment: parece que você faz tudo sozinho aqui no SOPT kkkk